# C function call is giving me a "too many arguments" error

Tags: c, function, memory, arguments

I'm getting a "too many arguments in function call" error in my C program. The error occurs at a line where I'm calling a function that has a fixed number of arguments. I'm not sure why I'm getting this error, as I'm not passing in more arguments than the function expects. Here's the code where the error occurs:

```
if (mkdir(path, 0777) == -1)
```

Here is full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1024
#define MAX_ARGS 10  

// Print the usage message for the program
void print_usage() {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: syscalls <command> [arguments]\n");
}

// Read the contents of a file and write them to stdout
int read_file(const char *path) {
    static char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s: %s\n", path, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    ssize_t num_read;
    while ((num_read = read(fd, buf, BUF_SIZE)) > 0) {
        if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, num_read) != num_read) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read %s: %s\n", path, strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (num_read == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read %s: %s\n", path, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

// Write a set of lines to a file
int write_file(const char *path, char *lines[], int num_lines) {
    int fd = open(path, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s: %s\n", path, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    int total_bytes = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_lines; i++) {
        const char *line = lines[i];
        size_t len = strlen(line);
        ssize_t num_written = pwrite(fd, line, len, total_bytes);
        if (num_written == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to write to %s: %s\n", path, strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
        total_bytes += num_written;
    }
    printf("Wrote %d B\n", total_bytes);
    return 0;
}

// Create a directory
int make_directory(const char *path) {
    if (mkdir(path, 0777) == -1) {
        if (errno == EEXIST) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s already exists\n", path);
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create %s: %s\n", path, strerror(errno));
        }
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

// List the contents of a directory
int list_directory(const char *path) {
    DIR *dir = opendir(path);
    if (dir == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open directory %s: %s\n", path, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    struct dirent *entry;
    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", entry->d_name);
    }

    if (closedir(dir) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to close directory %s: %s\n", path, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        print_usage();
        return 1;
    }
    
    char *command = argv[1];
    
    if (strcmp(command, "read") == 0) {
        if (argc != 3) {
            print_usage();
            return 1;
        }
        return read_file(argv[2]);
    } else if (strcmp(command, "write") == 0) {
        if (argc < 4 || argc > MAX_ARGS + 2) {
            print_usage();
            return 1;
        }
        return write_file(argv[2], argv + 3, argc - 3);
    } else if (strcmp(command, "mkdir") == 0) {
        if (argc != 3) {
            print_usage();
            return 1;
        }
        return make_directory(argv[2]);
    } else if (strcmp(command, "ls") == 0) {
        if (argc != 3) {
            print_usage();
            return 1;
        }
        return list_directory(argv[2]);
    } else {
        print_usage();
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I am getting this error in terminal:

```
syscalls.c: In function 'write_file':
syscalls.c:54:31: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pwrite' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         ssize_t num_written = pwrite(fd, line, len, total_bytes);
                               ^~~~~~
syscalls.c: In function 'make_directory':
syscalls.c:67:9: error: too many arguments to function 'mkdir'
     if (mkdir(path, 0777) == -1) {
         ^~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\include\unistd.h:56:0,
                 from syscalls.c:3:
c:\mingw\include\io.h:516:38: note: declared here
 _CRTIMP __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW  int mkdir (const char *);
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thank you

Comment: I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: Note that `mkdir()` isn't a standard c function. The Microsoft version takes one argument.

Comment: Please show the *exact* compiler output along with the compiler type and version, and the command used to run it.

Comment: I just edit my question you check the error

Comment: As you can see from the last line of the error: in your tools the function is `int mkdir (const char *);` which isn't the POSIX version.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre]. Aside from the attempt to use `mkdir` itself, what appears to be actually **necessary to reproduce** the error?

Answer (score 1):

`mkdir()` is not specified in the C standard. It is specified in the POSIX standard, which is more or less a superset of the C standard.
This declaration of `mkdir()`:

```
c:\mingw\include\io.h:516:38: note: declared here
_CRTIMP __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW  int mkdir (const char *);
```

is the Microsoft version of the function, which takes a single argument, and does not conform to the POSIX standard.

From [Microsoft's page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/mkdir?view=msvc-170):

> The Microsoft-implemented POSIX function name mkdir is a deprecated
> alias for the _mkdir function.

```
int _mkdir(
   const char *dirname
);
```

---

**Possible fix:**

```
#ifdef _CRTIMP
#define mkdir(d,m)  (mkdir)(d)
#endif
```

Credit: @chqrlie